# UINavigationControllerDelegate‘s didShowViewController method was called twice

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

      override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         navigationController!.delegate = self
      }

      func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, didShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
         print("showViewController")
      }

      func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
         print("sss")
      }

      func update() {
         let vc = SecondViewController()
         navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
      }
}
```

this is the first controller of my demo , and in console:

```
sss
showViewController
showViewController
```

the "didShowViewController"  was called twice.
I'm not sure what's going on

-----------------some test----------------------

I add some log in these method of controller : loadView,viewDidLoad ,viewWillAppear,viewDidAppear , and the order of these log is:

```
loadView
viewDidLoad
viewWillAppear
will:<NaviDemo.ViewController: 0x7fe8c9533050>
<NaviDemo.ViewController: 0x7fe8c9533050>
viewDidAppear
<NaviDemo.ViewController: 0x7fe8c9533050>
```

Comment: I've update solution for iOS 13
check https://stackoverflow.com/a/58169169/7332815

Answer (score 4):

I hit the same issue in my code. I was able to work around it by waiting until `viewDidAppear` to set the navigation delegate instead of setting it in `viewDidLoad`. To translate it to your example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
}

// ...

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    navigationController!.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: Workaround worked for me; I would however advise against force-unwrapping optionals - as this is an assignment, there is no reason to do this!

Comment: agree! I just copied the original code from the parent question.

Answer (score 1):

`didShowViewController` is called twice because the first time it is called when the navigation controller transitions to showing the view controller. And then it is called again by the navigation controller's own `viewDidAppear` when it appears on screen, using the `topViewController` as the controller param which in this case is the same as the controller the first time it was called.

Answer (score 0):

The `UINavigationController` has displayed two instances of a `UIViewController`

From the [`UINavigationControllerDelegate` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UINavigationControllerDelegate/navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:)

> Called just after the navigation controller displays a view
>   controller’s view and navigation item properties.

Instead of logging "showViewController", log the `UIViewController` instance to see what's going on

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, didShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
     print(viewController)
}
```

Comment: thank you  , I had tried your suggest,
<NaviDemo.ViewController: 0x7fba43c403d0>
<NaviDemo.ViewController: 0x7fba43c403d0>
 in console , it prints the same instance twice

Comment: why is the method called twice ? @James Zaghini