# UINavigationControllerDelegate method called twice

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have set up a very simple project with no storyboard, one window and one  UINavigationController containing a plain old UIViewController as rootViewController. In the AppDelegate I've set the UINavigationController's delegate to self and implemented

`navigationController:didShowViewController:animated` which contains 1 line:

`NSLog("didShow viewController")`

When I launch my app the UINavigationControllerDelegate method `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated` gets called twice.

AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var vc1: FirstViewController?
    var nav1: UINavigationController?

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        NSLog("didShow viewController")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        vc1 = FirstViewController()
        nav1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc1!)
        nav1?.delegate = self

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        if let window = window {
            window.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            window.rootViewController = nav1
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

FirstViewController:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I have tried this in more complicated environments - An app with a UITabBarController and 2 UINavigationControllers as the viewControllers for the UITabBarController. Oddly the UINavigationControllerDelegate methods fire twice the first time a UINavigationController is shown, but will only fire once after that.

Anyone have any insight as to how to correct this? What I believe to be correct behavior based on the documentation is that `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated` should be only called once in this sample app. I have also checke dot make sure the `navigationController` and `viewController` params in the delegate method are the same object.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here's the callstack from each call. All in UIKit code, not mine!

1st call:

```
29 elements
  - 0 : "0   ???                                 0x0000000115145377 0x0 + 4648620919"
  - 1 : "1   ???                                 0x0000000115145462 0x0 + 4648621154"
  - 2 : "2   Test                                0x0000000105f22d00 main + 0"
  - 3 : "3   Test                                0x0000000105f21e11 _TToFC4Test11AppDelegate20navigationControllerfTCSo22UINavigationController7didShowCSo16UIViewController8animatedSb_T_ + 97"
  - 4 : "4   UIKit                               0x0000000106bab7a8 -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:] + 1660"
  - 5 : "5   UIKit                               0x0000000106e8839e -[UINavigationTransitionView _notifyDelegateTransitionDidStopWithContext:] + 421"
  - 6 : "6   UIKit                               0x0000000106e88677 -[UINavigationTransitionView _cleanupTransition] + 629"
  - 7 : "7   UIKit                               0x0000000106a58f07 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 222"
  - 8 : "8   UIKit                               0x0000000106a54bcb +[UIViewAnimationState popAnimationState] + 305"
  - 9 : "9   UIKit                               0x0000000106e8810b -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 2582"
  - 10 : "10  UIKit                               0x0000000106bb01d1 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 3301"
  - 11 : "11  UIKit                               0x0000000106bb06b3 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 843"
  - 12 : "12  UIKit                               0x0000000106bb17f1 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 58"
  - 13 : "13  UIKit                               0x0000000106da32bc -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 231"
  - 14 : "14  UIKit                               0x0000000106a9020b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1268"
  - 15 : "15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010bfbf904 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146"
  - 16 : "16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010bfb3526 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 370"
  - 17 : "17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010bfb33a0 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24"
  - 18 : "18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010bf42e92 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294"
  - 19 : "19  QuartzCore                          0x000000010bf6f130 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 468"
  - 20 : "20  QuartzCore                          0x000000010bf6fb37 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 115"
  - 21 : "21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010910f717 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23"
  - 22 : "22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010910f687 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391"
  - 23 : "23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001090f4038 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 440"
  - 24 : "24  UIKit                               0x00000001069c702f -[UIApplication _run] + 468"
  - 25 : "25  UIKit                               0x00000001069cd0d4 UIApplicationMain + 159"
  - 26 : "26  Test                                0x0000000105f22d37 main + 55"
  - 27 : "27  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010a19a65d start + 1"
  - 28 : "28  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1"
```

2nd call:

```
20 elements
  - 0 : "0   ???                                 0x00000001151456e7 0x0 + 4648621799"
  - 1 : "1   ???                                 0x00000001151457d2 0x0 + 4648622034"
  - 2 : "2   Test                                0x0000000105f22d00 main + 0"
  - 3 : "3   Test                                0x0000000105f21e11 _TToFC4Test11AppDelegate20navigationControllerfTCSo22UINavigationController7didShowCSo16UIViewController8animatedSb_T_ + 97"
  - 4 : "4   UIKit                               0x0000000106ba949b -[UINavigationController viewDidAppear:] + 421"
  - 5 : "5   UIKit                               0x0000000106b7595e -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 704"
  - 6 : "6   UIKit                               0x0000000106b7863b __64-[UIViewController viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:]_block_invoke + 42"
  - 7 : "7   UIKit                               0x0000000106b76a7b -[UIViewController _executeAfterAppearanceBlock] + 86"
  - 8 : "8   UIKit                               0x00000001069d992f _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 634"
  - 9 : "9   UIKit                               0x00000001069c67bc _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 532"
  - 10 : "10  UIKit                               0x00000001069e957d __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_2 + 155"
  - 11 : "11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010910fb5c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12"
  - 12 : "12  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001090f4e54 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 356"
  - 13 : "13  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001090f45ee __CFRunLoopRun + 894"
  - 14 : "14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001090f4016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406"
  - 15 : "15  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010b100a24 GSEventRunModal + 62"
  - 16 : "16  UIKit                               0x00000001069cd0d4 UIApplicationMain + 159"
  - 17 : "17  Test                                0x0000000105f22d37 main + 55"
  - 18 : "18  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010a19a65d start + 1"
  - 19 : "19  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1"
```

Comment: try to add a breakpoint in the navigation delegate method and see the stack trace of the calling method.

Comment: I've added the callstacks above for each call. Thanks for having a look!

Comment: http://vastdevblog.vast.com/blog/2012/04/08/uiviewcontroller-life-cycle/ check out this blog

Comment: Put a breakpoint and see if the pointer to the View Controller is the same. I'm curious if it's in fact two separate view controllers getting displayed or only one.

Comment: Perhaps it gets called once when you set the root view controller, and once when you set the Nav controller on the window?

Comment: @JakeT. Yup both nav and view contorllers are same address each time. `2017-05-16 13:55:13.222 Test[3537:514823] Simulator user has requested new graphics quality: 100
2017-05-16 13:55:13.253 Test[3537:514823] didShow viewController <UINavigationController: 0x7f8f22805a00> <Test.FirstViewController: 0x7f8f22507730>
2017-05-16 13:55:13.256 Test[3537:514823] didShow viewController <UINavigationController: 0x7f8f22805a00> <Test.FirstViewController: 0x7f8f22507730>`

Comment: I hit this issue as well. I worked around it by setting the navigation delegate in viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48568202/52691

Answer (score 3):

After experimenting, I found that iOS 13 had made this issue for the first UINavigationController in UITabBarController more complicated.

the first UINavigationController won't be called for the call stack `[UINavigationController viewDidAppear:]`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.delegate = self
    }

}

extension ViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        print("willShow")
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        print("didShow")
    }

}
```

the output will be

```
willShow
didShow -> this one is from call stack `[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews]`
```

for the first tab.

Which means that if you are using the old workaround down below below iOS 13 then the first time show first VC and only first VC's `didShow` won't be called.

the new workaround I can think of will be still set the delegate in `viewDidLoad` but try to stop the first call of VC other than first in TabBarVC.

the `didShow` will be call in this order

```
LAUNCH APP

VC1 willShow 
VC1 didShow `[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews]`

SELECT SECOND TAB

VC2 willShow 
VC2 didShow `[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews]`
VC2 didShow `[UINavigationController viewDidAppear:]` -> this is the one I try to get rid off

SELECT BACK TO FIRST TAB

VC1 willShow 
VC1 didShow `[UINavigationController viewDidAppear:]`

SELECT BACK TO SECOND TAB

VC2 willShow 
VC2 didShow `[UINavigationController viewDidAppear:]`
```

so make a flag to let other than first UINavigationControllers' `didShow` not be called only for the first time.

here is the demo project to solve it [Demo](https://github.com/andrew54068/NavigationControllerDelegateDemo)

---

below iOS 13
if you only need

`func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)`

then there is work around to set like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.delegate = self
    }

}

extension ViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        // do something
    }

}
```

but there is a issue that

`func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)`

will not be called at the first time cause you set delegate too late, but the second time the same `ViewController` instance `willShow` method get called normally.

p.s. if you want to implement `didShow` method in UINavigationController, you have to set delegate like this:

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        delegate = self
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }

}

extension NavigationController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        print("will")
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        print("did")
    }

}
```

since `didShow` method get called in `super.viewDidAppear(animated)`